# Django's render_to_string produces <br> tags

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Django 1.10, Python 2.7

I'm using `render_to_string` function to get rendered content of a template and use it in content of an admin's custom field.
So I have code that looks like that in Admin's class:

```
    def checks(self, obj):
       # ...
       return render_to_string('template.html', context)

    checks.allow_tags = True
```

In `template.html` I have only one table:

```
<table>
    {% for something in somethings %}
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But this produces a lot of `<br>`s before actual table:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
...
<br>
# Actual table
<br>
<br>
```

What's the problem in this case?

UPD. I can kinda "fix it" by removing spaces and line breaks from my template file. But this is not the way I want it to work, obviously.

Comment: Does your `template.html` have spaces before and after the `<table>` tag?

Comment: @EvansMurithi nope. It starts with `<table>` and ends with `</table>`.

Answer (score 2):

`allow_tags` is [deprecated since version 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> In older versions, you could add an allow_tags attribute to the method
> to prevent auto-escaping. This attribute is deprecated as it’s safer
> to use format_html(), format_html_join(), or mark_safe() instead.

Try:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

def checks(self, obj):
       # ...
       return mark_safe(render_to_string('template.html', context))
```

Comment: from django's src: `class AdminReadonlyField(object): ... def contents(self):...  if hasattr(value, "__html__"): result_repr = value ... else: ... result_repr = linebreaksbr(result_repr)`. This means that if you return mark_safe(), it would not call `linebreaksbr`, and you would not see `<br/>`s.  Please try again.